# How to extract "entry.id" from Google Form using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, google-forms

I am trying to automate a **google form**.
I extracted entry text using following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScio8_OkrBe7wtmw8GeUENvLFVUCAV6eyFOLWhfDbPuunG0Yw/viewform')
cont = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
vals = cont.find_all('div', {'class':'freebirdFormviewerComponentsQuestionBaseTitle exportItemTitle freebirdCustomFont'})
print(vals[0].text)
```

Result: **'Name'**

But I am unable to extract entry.id from:

```
<div jsname="06bZLc">
    <input type="hidden" name="entry.2005620554" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="entry.1045781291" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="entry.1065046570" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="entry.1166974658" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="entry.839337160" value>
</div>
```

I tried using following code:

```
v = cont.find('div', {'jsname': 'o6bZLc'})
x = v.find_all('input')
y = v.find_all_next('input',{'type':'hidden'})
print(x)
print(y)
```

Result :

```
[]
[<input name="fvv" type="hidden" value="1"/>, <input name="draftResponse" type="hidden" value='[null,null,"-1617617719642916240"]
'/>, <input name="pageHistory" type="hidden" value="0"/>, <input name="fbzx" type="hidden" value="-1617617719642916240"/>]
```

But I couldn't get childrens inside `<div jsname="06bZLc">`.
Can you please help me to get those childrens.

URL : [form link](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScio8_OkrBe7wtmw8GeUENvLFVUCAV6eyFOLWhfDbPuunG0Yw/viewform)

Answer (score 2):

The ids are added dynamically via JavaScript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see them. You can try this example to load them:

```
import re
import json
import requests


url = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScio8_OkrBe7wtmw8GeUENvLFVUCAV6eyFOLWhfDbPuunG0Yw/viewform'
html_data = requests.get(url).text

data = json.loads( re.search(r'FB_PUBLIC_LOAD_DATA_ = (.*?);', html_data, flags=re.S).group(1) )

def get_ids(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k, v in d.items():
            yield from get_ids(v)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        if len(d) == 3 and d[1] is None:
            yield d[0]
        else:
            for v in d:
                yield from get_ids(v)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for i in get_ids(data):
    print(i)
```

Prints:

```
2005620554
1065046570
1166974658
839337160
```

Comment: It only returned 4 values but it should return all 5 entries values .can you check it once more please

Comment: I got that thank you bro. I just replaced len(d)==3 by len(d)>1

Answer (score 1):

Please Check this out

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
html="""<div jsname="06bZLc">
    <input type="hidden" name="entry.2005620554" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="entry.1045781291" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="entry.1065046570" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="entry.1166974658" value>
    <input type="hidden" name="entry.839337160" value>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
divs = soup.find_all("input")
for i in divs:
    print ((i.attrs['name']).split(".")[1])
```

Output : 2005620554 1045781291 1065046570 1166974658 839337160

**Edit**
Using the google form link you provided

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScio8_OkrBe7wtmw8GeUENvLFVUCAV6eyFOLWhfDbPuunG0Yw/viewform')
cont = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
divs = soup.find_all("input")
for i in divs:
    print ((i.attrs['name']).split(".")[1])
```

Output : 2005620554 1045781291 1065046570 1166974658 839337160

**Edit**
Based on the 2nd comment

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r=requests.get('https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScio8_OkrBe7wtmw8GeUENvLFVUCAV6eyFOLWhfDbPuunG0Yw/viewform')
cont = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
divs = soup.find_all("input")
nums=[]
for i in divs:
    nums.extend((i.attrs['name']).split("."))
num=[int(i) for i in nums if i.isdigit()]
```

Output : [2005620554 1045781291 1065046570 1166974658 839337160]

Comment: But You Are using a hard coded response if the site changes the code will break and also you are using a hard coded html doc.

Comment: while your this edited code snippet is also harcoded because you are using the index position of second occurrence of the input boxes if the site manager changes the position the code will break immediate.

Comment: a very well checked it thats why commented on the edit.

Comment: @Karthik sir I am getting KeyError: 'name' can you please help

Comment: @UjjalBaniya Please check if you have used quotation marks properly and use the 2nd edit snippet

Comment: @Karthik I have copied your 2nd edit snippet still getting error :(